# How to express one-to-one correspondence for uncountable noun

Tags: uncountable-nouns

> 1. Ramp A produces light of an intensity that depends on electric current supplied to it from battery A.
> 2. Ramp B produces light of an intensity that depends on electric current supplied to it from battery B.

I am trying to combine the above two sentences I created.  The following is a sentence I drafted:

> Ramps A and B **each** produce light of an intensity that depends on
>   electric current supplied to them **respectively** from batteries A and B.

It seems that this sentence is hard to understand.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for:

> Ramps A and B **each produces** light of an intensity that depends on electric current supplied to them from batteries A and B, **respectively**.

- produce has to be in singular (because of "each");
- battery has to be in plural (because there are two of them);
- "respectively" is usually after the enumeration (but some exceptions may exist).

As you noticed, a more complex sentence is more difficult to understand than a simple one (or two simple ones).

Note (thanks to **Jason Bassford**):
If you want to use "produce" in **plural** form, then you need to use **"both"** instead of **"each"**:

> Ramps A and B **both produce** light of an intensity that depends on electric current supplied to them from batteries A and B, respectively.

Comment: Regarding the plural form, they are careless mistakes, so I corrected them.

Comment: I was not aware of that. OK.

Comment: @rama9 **Each** needs to be follows by a *singular* verb. It should be *each* **produces**, not *each* **produce**.  (*It* ***produces***, *they* ***produce***.)

Comment: @JasonBassford: I need some clarification for my own knowledge. I know that "Each of X, Y, Z..." requires verb in singular form. For some (twisted?) reason, the subject "X, Y, Z each..." should require plural, at least according to my ears. So, do you confirm that moving "each" after the enumeration still requires verb in singular? Thank you.

Comment: I was not aware of me thinking "both", but your explanation makes total sense. With your permission, I will add this to the answer. Thank you.

Comment: @virolino Yes, go ahead. I had just changed my mind to expand that into an answer myself, but I'll let you beat me to it. ;)

Comment: What you *want* to hear is *Ramps A and B **both** produce light*, so your mind is playing tricks on itself. But, syntactically, *each* is always singular and *both* is always plural. (At least in the case of singular selected objects.) If you want your sentence to be plural, you need to use *both*.

Comment: Thank you. I was quite puzzled when I noticed your comment gone :D